# How to convert value object into array in react js

Tags: javascript

I have below kind of data.

`{"username":"[\"abc\"]","password":"[\"asd\"]"}`.

I want to convert it like

`{"username":"abc","password":"asd"}` .

I am trying JSON.stringify but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert that obj to string you can use Regex replace

`JSON.stringify(z).replace(/(\[\\"|\\"\])/g,"");`

```js
obj = {
  "username": "[\"abc\"]",
  "password": "[\"asd\"]"
};
let result = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/(\[\\"|\\"\])/g, "");

document.write(result);
```

or use this to remove characters & keep it Object not String

```js
obj = {
  "username": "[\"abc\"]",
  "password": "[\"asd\"]"
};

replace_=(s)=>s.replace(/(\["|"\])/g, "");

obj.password = replace_(obj.username);
obj.username = replace_(obj.username);

console.log(obj);
```

**or**

if you have array of objects & you want to remove those characters & keep the data as Objects  use this

```js
ObjList=[
{"username":"[\"ac\"]","password":"[\"ad\"]"},
{"username":"[\"abc\"]","password":"[\"asd\"]"},
{"username":"[\"abc\"]","password":"[\"asd\"]"},
{"username":"[\"abc\"]","password":"[\"asd\"]"}
];

ObjList.forEach((v,i)=>{
ObjList[i].password=v.password.slice(2,-2);
ObjList[i].username=v.username.slice(2,-2);
});

console.log(ObjList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This has nothing to do with react and react cannot help you here.

I assume your input data is JSON and you want to create JSON again. The input data is not optimal, it looks like you double encoded the JSON somehow. Ideally it would look like this:

```
{"username":["abc"],"password":["asd"]}
```

I.e. the values are actual arrays and not strings containing more JSON.

However, working with your original data, this is how it would go:

1. Parse the JSON into an object with `JSON.parse`.
2. Parse the value of each property (which is again JSON) into arrays with `JSON.parse`.
3. Assign the first element of the resulting arrays back to the properties.
4. Convert object to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Implementation:

```js
// assuming `input` contains the JSON data, i.e. something like
var input = String.raw`{"username":"[\"abc\"]","password":"[\"asd\"]"}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(input);
obj.username = JSON.parse(obj.username)[0];
obj.password = JSON.parse(obj.password)[0];

var output = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(output);
```

---

If you manage to produce "better" input data (in which case why not generate it exactly as you need it though?) and don't have nested JSON but proper arrays as I have shown at the beginning, then the steps woul be the same except you wouldn't have to call `JSON.parse` on the properties.